# How to put statistical information on the output diagram with hist()?

Tags: r

I made the following histogram. I want to display a stats box with a border here, like the image on [this sites image](https://root.cern/doc/v610/pict1_combinedFit.C.png), and write various information there. In addition, it is assumed that you will also write legends for multiple histograms.

[image]

As a result of research, I found that ROOT has a [similar function](https://root.cern/doc/v610/combinedFit_8C.html), but I would like to realize this with R. How can I do this with R?
The xlsx file I used is large, so I uploaded it [here](https://filebin.net/ayd83h6wqhl78sjw).

```
library(readxl)
file = read_excel("./data.xlsx")
summary(file)
data = file[["foo[%]"]]
par(las=1, family="Century gothic", xaxs="i", yaxs="i", cex.main=3, cex.lab=1.1, cex.axis=1.1, font.lab=2, font.axis=2)

h = hist(data, yaxt="n", tck=0.03, breaks=seq(18,18.35,0.01), main=NA, xlab="xaxis", ylab="freq", border=NA, col="#00000000", ylim=c(0,100))
axis(2, tck=0.03, at=c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100))
grid()
lines(rep(h$breaks, each=2)[-c(1,2*length(h$breaks))], rep(h$counts, each=2), lwd=3)

box()
```

Comment: Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038 before posting.

Comment: @jay.sf Thanks for comment. I uploaded the file I used for better reproducibility.

Comment: You may use the `legend()` function to display your statistics. If your question is how to compute these statistics, that's way too broad.

Answer (score 0):

@jay.sf's suggestion is a little tricky to implement.  Here's an example that comes close, but it's not perfect:  the spacing is wrong.  Maybe someone can improve it?

```r
statname <- expression("Entries", "Mean", "Std Dev", chi^2/"ndf", "Prob", "Constant", "Slope")
statvalue <- expression(5000, 19.59, 18.61, 131.1/115, 0.1447, 5.54 %+-% 0.04, 
                       -0.0514 %+-% 0.0011)

plot(1)
legend("topright", title = "hB",
       legend = c(statname, statvalue), 
       ncol = 2, 
       x.intersp = 0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It uses `expression()` for the entries because you have math in them; you might be able to do it reasonably well with special characters instead.  I couldn't find a way to set the spacing of the two columns differently:  your example had the names flush left and the values flush right.  Nor could I set the column widths separately.  Probably if you really want to fine tune this, you'll have to write your own function based on the `legend` function.